# Identify anonymous inner class implementations of a functional interface

Tags: intellij-idea

When a functional interface is implemented a lambda is preferred. But sometimes the single abstract method is not the only method implemented. Often these helper methods can be moved elsewhere and the anonymous inner class replaced with a lambda.

Intellij has a structural search template for anonymous classes:

```java
new $AnonymousClass$() {}
```

The results are too many.
Here is my attempt at finding all method calls that could be a lambda

```java
$ReturnType$ $Method$(new $AnonymousClass$() {
  @Override
  $ReturnType$ $Method$ ($ParameterType$ $Parameter$);
});
```

Firstly, I'm not able to set a count on the method (since it needs to be ==1).
Then this syntax also doesn't work. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried the "Java | Java language level migration aids | Java 8 | Anonymous type can be replaced with lambda" inspection?

Comment: It doesn't work if there are other methods implemented. That's exactly why I'm asking